# Excel If Formula Error

Tags: excel

I am working on excel sheet with multiple formulas. One thing that made me wonder is the IF formula. Consider the below table filled from Cell `E3` to `G5`.

[image: Excel Formula]

The formula that I am using at cell G5 is 
`=IF((G3+G4)=(E5+F5),+G3+G4,"OFF")`

Considering the values from example itself, the formula should evaluate `TRUE` and total the `G3` and `G4`, but I am not sure why it not evaluating `TRUE`. I checked for number format for all the cells, it is having the format as accounting.

Comment: How are the values populated?  My guess is you are suffering from numbers that have more significant digits in the decimal than are being shown.  There for they are not exactly the same.  Increase the decimal shown in all the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the numbers before adding them:

```
=IF((ROUND(G3,2)+ROUND(G4,2))=(ROUND(E5,2)+ROUND(F5,2)),G3+G4,"OFF")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calculating any of the values by formula then you may have a very small decimal that the formatting is dropping off.  For example if G4 = -59400003.570001 then your value will be "OFF".

I recommend hard-coding the values and verifying that the values are truly to the penny and not smaller.